# Add timestamps to compiled sass/scss

Tags: css, compass-sass, sass

Is it possible to automatically add a timestamp on the compiled CSS file using SASS?
e.g.

```
/* CSS Compiled on: {date+time} */
...compiled css goes here...
```

I've checked the SASS and Compass docs but no mention of such a feature.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know of any built-in SASS or Compass feature for this, but it's not too hard to add a custom Ruby function to do it. (See the section entitled "[Adding Custom Functions](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#adding_custom_functions)" in the SASS reference [here](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html).)

Your file with the Ruby function would look like this (let's call it "timestamp.rb"):

```
module Sass::Script::Functions
    def timestamp()
        return Sass::Script::String.new(Time.now.to_s)
    end
end
```

And you'd reference the new timestamp function in your SASS file like this:

```
/*!
 * CSS Compiled on: #{timestamp()}
 */
```

You just need to make sure your "timestamp.rb" file is loaded when you compile the SASS, either by requiring it from a Compass config file, or by using the `--require` parameter with the SASS command line. When all is said and done, you should get output like the following:

```
/*
 * CSS Compiled on: 2012-10-23 08:53:03 -0400
 */
```

Comment: and how do I require it from the config.rb?

Comment: @barraponto Include a line in the config.rb file like this (assuming timestamp.rb is in the same directory as config.rb):
`require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'timestamp.rb')`

Comment: @hopper, this works beautifully, i just added the function into my config.rb file. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the command line version of SCSS you can do the following:

1. Install [sass-timestamp](https://github.com/madastro/sass-timestamp)

   `gem install sass-timestamp`
2. Use it within your code like (see [documentation](https://github.com/madastro/sass-timestamp) for more information)

   `/* Compiled on #{timestamp()} */`
3. Require it on the command line

   `scss -r sass-timestamp ...`
4. Output will be

   `/* Compiled on 2015-02-02 13:01:40 +0800 */`

Note: Use `#{unix_timestamp()}` for a unix timestamp

Answer (score 1):

*I don't know if everyone needs it (cause the question is a long time answered ago),
but a simple solution is to write the timestamp/date
to a single sass/scss file as SASS variable,
import them to the location where the timestamp should be
and then let a comment in sass write them out.*

Nothing to install, compile or anything else - just using scripts and sass:

**1.) Write the timestamp to a separate sass file: (Here a dos-script, but you can also use any other script/language to generate the simple file):**

```
echo $BuildTimeStamp : "%date% %time%"> _timestamp.scss
```

**2.) Import the generated file with the timestamp:**

```
@import '_timestamp.scss';
```

**3.) Write the header out as comment:**

```
/*! Automatic build at: #{$BuildTimeStamp} */
```

Write the timestamp before you call the original sass command
and it will also work without the need to install, build or do anything else.