# Using Compass from Ruby (not shell)

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

I am building a script in Ruby where I would like to compile a single SCSS file using Compass. I am trying to make this as simple as possible, and would like to avoid using a config.rb file. I just want to set a couple settings via straight Ruby and tell Compass to compile a single SCSS file into a CSS file.

I know that this has to be possible but I have not been able to find any decent documentation on how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right, there's not really any comprehensive documentation on how to use Compass from Ruby. This is unfortunate, but let's not let little details like documentation stop us!

## A First Attempt

When I was looking to do the same thing, I just poked around the Compass [source](https://github.com/Compass/compass/tree/stable/cli/lib/compass) and was able put together this little Ruby script. At first glance it seems to do the trick:

```
require 'compass'
require 'sass/plugin'

compiler = Compass::Compiler.new(
    # Compass working directory
    '.',
    # Input directory
    'styles/scss',
    # Output directory
    'styles/css',
    # Compass options
    { :style => :compressed }
)

compiler.compile('test.scss', 'test.css')
```

But apparently Compass has a bunch of default configuration options that aren't automatically included when invoking the compiler constructor directly (of which the SASS `load_path` is one). This can lead to errors when trying to import Compass functions and mixins, such as:

> error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3

## Compass <1.0.0 (a.k.a. "the old way")

Here's how to call the compiler *without* overriding those defaults:

```
require 'compass'

Compass.add_configuration(
    {
        :project_path => '.',
        :sass_path => 'styles/scss',
        :css_path => 'styles/css'
    },
    'custom' # A name for the configuration, can be anything you want
)
Compass.compiler.compile('test.scss', 'test.css')
```

However, as of Compass version 1.0.0, `Compass.compiler` has been deprecated in favor of `Compass.sass_compiler`, leading to...

## Compass >=1.0.0 (a.k.a. "the new way")

With thanks to [@philipp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687901/philipp) for finding [how to use the new API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399962/compass-from-ruby-sasscompiler-not-found), we can update this snippet again to work with `Compass.sass_compiler`:

```
require 'compass'
require 'compass/sass_compiler'

Compass.add_configuration(
    {
        :project_path => '.',
        :sass_path => 'styles/scss',
        :css_path => 'styles/css'
    },
    'custom' # A name for the configuration, can be anything you want
)

compiler = Compass.sass_compiler({
  :only_sass_files => [
    'styles/scss/test.scss'
  ]
})

compiler.compile!
```

Comment: Awesome! This is perfect! I am running into a little glitch when using it with `bundle exec`. I keep getting errors that compass cannot load any mixins. I assume that its an environment variable that needs to be set. Would you happen to know what needs to get set?

Comment: I should have added the error that I was getting... `error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3.`

Comment: I had started another question. I thought it was a different issue. However, I now think that its directly related.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13160660/compass-mixins-not-found-when-using-directly-from-ruby.

Comment: Yep, you're right. The options hash in the explicit constructor doesn't get merged with the default Compass options, wiping out the sass load path configuration. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Is there a way to pass in variables from ruby when compiling like this?

Comment: @Christian You can use [custom functions](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#adding_custom_functions) to access Ruby values from your stylesheet via function call. For example, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022461/add-timestamps-to-compiled-sass-scss/13031025#13031025) of mine demonstrates passing a timestamp this way, just replace the implementation to return whatever value you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the compile method from the command line. You can specify every option there. To see all of the options, run `compass help compile`.

Below's an example. It will output the compiled css file in the same directory as the test.scss file.

```
file_name = "absolute/path/to/test.scss"
system "compass compile #{file_name} --sass-dir . --css-dir ."
```

You could specify and interpolate as many options as you wish. Also check this for running commands in ruby:

[Running command line commands within Ruby script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159945/running-command-line-commands-within-ruby-script)

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to try and keep away from forking system processes.