# Compass mixins not found when using directly from ruby

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

I am building a new ruby script using GLI gem that uses Compass within. However, whenever I run the app using `bundle exec` SASS/Compass can never seem to find the mixins that I include in my .scss file. I get the following error...

`error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3.`

I know the solution is to set an environment variable. However, I have no clue as to which variable needs to be set.

**Update**:

I should have added that this is a follow up to another post that I had - [Using Compass from Ruby (not shell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129789/using-compass-from-ruby-not-shell)

Here is the code that I am using to invoke compass from my app.

```
require 'compass'
require 'sass/plugin'

compiler = Compass::Compiler.new('.','.','.',{:style => :compact})
compiler.compile(sass_file,css_file)
```

Here is the error that is getting thrown

> error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3.
>
> Load path: /Volumes/MacRAID/joeworkman/Desktop/stake-test/Badges/Badges.source/Contents

I originally thought that this only happened when I was running under `bundle exec`. However, its does happen every time even if I were to run in it normally.

**Update #2**:

I am pretty certain that this is a SASS `:load_paths` issue. If I set my `SASS_PATH` environment variable to the below value everything works. I don't want to depend on environment variables though.

`~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets`

Comment: Why do you need to add an environment variable? You should lay your cards on the table if you want help with your hand.

Comment: @coreyward I had rushed my question. All my cards should be laid out now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you check out the answers on the below post. Between my findings posted here and the suggestions made on the other post, the question is answered.

[Using Compass from Ruby (not shell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129789/using-compass-from-ruby-not-shell)