# Add timestamps to compiled javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, compilation, sprockets

I'm using (Ruby-based) Middleman as a front-end site compiler and I want to get build timestamps in my SCSS and JS. I found this solution to add timestamps to SCSS: [Add timestamps to compiled sass/scss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022461/add-timestamps-to-compiled-sass-scss)

Is there an equivalent for JavaScript compiled using Sprockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Sprockets provides an ERB engine for preprocessing assets using embedded Ruby code. Append .erb to a CSS or JavaScript asset's filename to enable the ERB engine.

Sprockets processes multiple engine extensions in order from right to left, so you can use multiple engines with a single asset. For example, to have a CoffeeScript asset that is first preprocessed with ERB, use the extension .js.coffee.erb

(The above is from the Sprockets README)

For example, if you have a file hello.js.coffee.erb then you can put this in it:

```
<%= Time.now.utc.to_s %>
```

Comment: Follow up query... I'm trying to get a local timezone timestamp:
`Time.zone = "Australia/Sydney"`
`Time.zone.now.to_s`
 and I can't figure out the error: `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` - any ideas?

Comment: Yes, see Rails ActiveSupport TimeWithZone. You can use ActiveSupport even if you're not using a Rails app. Heads up that UTC tends to be easier and more portable.