# Add timestamps to compiled sass/scss (Dart Sass)

Tags: css, dart, sass

As in [Add timestamps to compiled sass/scss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022461/add-timestamps-to-compiled-sass-scss/13031025#13031025) suggested, adding custom functions via a ruby file was working like a charm in the past. But with Ruby Sass being deprecated, that does not work anymore.

In the past, we had additional functions to print a comment into the compiled CSS with information like, who compiled it (Etc.getlogin), with which version of sass it was compiled and a timestamp to see how old the file is.

We'd like to continue with this, but using an updated version of sass, like the Dart Sass implementation suggested by https://sass-lang.com.

How can I add such functions in Dart Sass?

Comment: How are you compiling your sass file ? Via a task runner, via CLI ? Not that I'll know how to help you, but those informations might be useful.

Comment: Via CLI inside of a bash Script. So far we were calling `sass -r custom_functions.rb ...` which included the Ruby File.